# Matrix of shape operator of the sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

**Problem:** Let $M$ be a sphere of radius $a$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, defined by $$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2. $$ Parametrize the sphere using spherical coordinates $$x = a \sin \phi \cos \theta \\ y = a \sin \phi \sin \theta \\ z = a \cos \phi $$ where $0 \leq \phi < \pi, 0 \leq \theta < 2 \pi$.

Then for each $p \in M, e_1 = \partial/\partial\phi$ and $e_2 = \partial/ \partial \theta$ is a basis for the tangent space $T_p M$ for $p \in M$. Let $N_p$ be the unit outward normal vector at $p$ on the sphere.

Find the matrix of the shape operator of the sphere with respect to the basis $e_1, e_2$.

**Attempt:** I need to calculate $L(e_j) = - D_{e_j} N$ and then find the matrix $[a^{i}_{j}]$ such that $L(e_j) = \sum a^{i}_{j} e_i. $ Here $L$ denotes the shape operator.

I know that in cartesian coordinates, a normal unit vector is $N = \frac{1}{a} (x, y, z)$. But do I have to write this first in the $(\theta, \phi)$ basis?

I would calculate e.g. $$ D_{\partial_{\phi}} \frac{1}{a} (a \sin \phi \cos \theta, a \sin \phi \sin \theta, a \cos \phi) \\ = ( \cos \phi \cos \theta, \cos \phi \sin \theta, - \sin \phi). $$ But I need to write this as a linear combination of the basis vectors $\partial_{\phi}$ and $\partial_{\theta}$ to find the matrix representation?

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to do.

Comment: I did, and I found $N = \hat{r}$ in the $(\hat{r}, \hat{\phi}, \hat{\theta})$ basis. But then if I calculate $D_{e_i} N$ I get zero?

Comment: What you have to find is $-D_{\partial_{\phi}} N(\phi,\theta)$ and $-D_{\partial_{\theta}} N(\phi,\theta)$ in the $({\partial_{\phi}},{\partial_{\theta}})$ basis.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that this exercise is from the book *Differential Geometry* of Loring Tu. It is misleading that in the body of the exercise appear the map of the change from polar to Cartesian coordinates, or at least I didn't use this map to solve the exercise.

This is what I did: define the map $f(x,y,z):=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}-a$, then $f^{-1}(0)=a\mathbb{S}^2$, and as zero is a regular value of $f$ then we find that $\nabla f(x,y,z)=\tfrac1{a}(x,y,z)$ is the outward pointing unit normal vector to every $(x,y,z)\in a\mathbb{S}^2$, therefore
$$
N=\frac1{a}\left(x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)
$$
and from the definition of the shape operator you get
$$
L(e_1)=-\frac1{a}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi }\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi }\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi }\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)=-\frac1{a}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi }
$$
where the last identity follow easily applying the coordinate functions $x,y,z$ to the right of both expressions for the vector field. Therefore in basis $e_1,e_2$ we find that $L=-\tfrac1a\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0& 1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.∎

Comment: One of the principal diagonal entries of $L$ should zero which corresponds to the curvature in the $z$ direction.