# Contradiction with the dimension of shape operator matrix

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

**Context** My question is about the matrix dimension of the shape operator.

In order to avoid misunderstanding let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular surface and $$\psi(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$$ be a chart on a open subset $W\subset S$. So, we have the induced basis of $T_pM$ given by $\left\{\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial u},\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial v}\right\}$ which allow us to define the *Gauss map*

$$p \mapsto N(u,v)=\frac{\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial u}\land \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial v}}{\big\vert\big\vert \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial u}\land \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial v}\big\vert\big\vert}$$

Now we can finally define the *shape operator* $S:\mathfrak X(W)\rightarrow \mathfrak X(W)$; $S(X)=- D_XN$

**Question**

The matrix that represents the linear operator $D_XN$ lies on the space of $3\times 2$ matrices ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120454/matrix-representation-of-shape-operator) we have a very good derivation about this fact), so by definition of $S$, its matrix representation should also lies on the space of $3\times 2$ matrices.

But at the same time when I'm looking on textbooks I only find that this matrix is a $2\times 2$ matrix whose entries are given by the the one and second fundamental forms coefficients ([here](https://maths.dur.ac.uk/users/mark.a.powell/M435-chapter-4-2nd-FF-curvature.pdf) gives the formula I'm talking about and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3270824/matrix-of-shape-operator-of-the-sphere) we have an example).

**How can I should understand whats going on and how can I interpret this conceptual difference envolved ?**

Thank you in advance for any hint about this question :)

Comment: The linked post does not say the shape operator is represented by a $3 \times 2$ matrix: The _values_ of $-D_{X}N$ at a point $p$ are vectors in $\mathbf{R}^3$, but they lie in the tangent plane at $p$ to the surface, so can be expressed as linear combinations of coordinate vectors on the surface. There are two such vectors, so the matrix of the shape operator is $2 \times 2$.

Comment: I agree with you, but I did an example with surface $z=xy^2$ and things got weid because the matrix of shape operator $2\times 2$ was exactly the first four entries of matrix $3\times 2$ given by $\left(DN\left(\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial u}\right),DN\left(\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial v}\right)\right)$, this can't be a coincidence but I don't see a reason for that.

Comment: What is $\mathcal X(W)$ supposed to mean here? If you fix a point $P\in S$, then the shape operator maps the tangent plane $T_PS$ to the tangent plane of the unit sphere at $N(P)$, and this is again $T_PS$. As you vary $P$, you are taking a vector field $X$ on $W$ and getting another vector field on $W$. You must write these vector fields in terms of the basis you've indicated.

Comment: $X\in \mathfrak{X}(W)$ is just a vector field defined on this open set $W\subset S$. The problem is, I have a basis $\left\{\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial u},\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial v}\right\}$of $T_p S$ induced by the parametrization $\psi=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$. So, they're $3\times 1$ vectors implying that, the matrix of $D_p N$ in this basis is $\left( D_pN\left(\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial u}\right),D_pN\left(\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial u}\right)\right)$ i.e a $3\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: At the same time, as $T_p S\simeq \mathbb{R}^2$ we sure can representate the matrix of shape operator as a $2\times 2$ matrix. But I really don't understand how this don't contradict what I said above.